# Maven plugin maven-antrun-plugin copy option does not overwrite

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a problem with this maven plugin and I don't really know how to solve it.
I am trying to copy some resources to "${basedir}/../server/a/base-store" to "${basedir}/../resources/store/base_certificate_store_prod/base-store"

However I use "overwrite" on copy. But at the final end under "${basedir}/../server/a/base-store" the files are added and the others which were before still exist.
I would like the hole "base-store" directory to be replaced.

```
<profile>
    <id>PROD</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-prod-base-store</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${basedir}/../server/a" overwrite="true">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/../resources/store/base_certificate_store_prod" includes="**/*"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the directory first and then copy.